# Reference Aubin T.- Espaces de Sobolev sur les varietes Riemanniennes. Bull. Sc. Math. 100, (1976) 149-173

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, embeddings, paper-request

I have been searching without success for the reference:

Aubin T.- Espaces  de Sobolev sur les  varietes  Riemanniennes.  Bull.  Sc.  Math.  100,  (1976)  149-173

It is cited in many related works. In particular, I cannot find a discussion of Sobolev spaces on Lipschitz subdomains of compact boundaryless Riemannian manifolds. Every result references the above, which is extremely difficult to find.

Does anyone know where to find it?

Thank you

Comment: Ummm... it's not clear what kind of answer you expect. You can look for the journal in which that article was published in the libraries of the universities physically close to you. A Google search makes it clear that it is not available on the internet. Finally, there is the illegal option, that many of us use - but for obvious reasons I shall not state it here. Other than that - what do you hope for?

Comment: Looking at [the site of the Bull. Sc. Math.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/bulletin-des-sciences-mathematiques/issues?page=2), the journal has been available in digital format only from 1998. As such, the article that you are looking for does not even have a [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier), therefore getting it in physical format from some library seems the only available option.

Comment: I have been looking in University libraries in Zurich and Montreal and could not find it. If someone were to know of a library where I could find it I would contact this library. Also sometimes people have legal copies.

Comment: @E.Schulz: I have a scanned copy of the paper (that I got from the library at my current institution). My email is easy to find. Send me an email and I can send it to you.

Comment: I've needed this in the past but never knew this reference. It's pretty straightfoward though, if you don't need a sharp constant. You can use the extension theorem found in Stein's book "Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions" on each coordinate patch containing the boundary to extend the function to the full manifold and apply the Sobolev inequality that holds on the compact manifold.

Comment: I had a xeroxed copy of it quite a few years ago, but I don't know where I left it. As far as I remember, the argument there goes essentially as Deane sketched in his comment. I don't think Aubin obtains the best constants in this paper, because the latter is cited precisely in the landmark J. Diff. Geom. paper where Aubin obtains the best constants for the Sobolev inequality for the first time (also done independently by Talenti).

Comment: @WillieWong I am quite late to this question, but it happens that I am also looking for exactly the same paper, but neither the library of my current affiliation nor other well-known internet sources seem to have this publication. Do you still have a copy and mind sharing it with me?

Comment: @G.Blaickner I still have the paper if you need it. Let me know.